# How to stop certain warning logging in error.log?

Tags: errors, logging

bbPress has an annoying error about `bbp_setup_current_user was called incorrectly.` [bbPress topic](https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/bbp_setup_current_user-was-called-incorrectly/) and [bbPress ticket #2412](https://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2412), and it looks like nothing will change to fix it.

On the site we used to use forum as a support platform, but has since then moved to a ticket system, so I've closed the forums, but you can look through them. I've also commented out the notice that was thrown in the backend because of it, but the problem is that the `error.log` on the server is filled with such errors (it's 85MB during the last 4 days). It's all like this:

> [Fri Aug 26 02:00:52.251831 2016] [:error] [pid 1832] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:32824] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'bbp_setup_current_user' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524

So is there any kind of command I can use to suppress the writing of this specific warning in the error log? I'd still like to have possible errors written here.

Comment: how about fixing the bug? ;)

Comment: The bug, as stated by the bbPress developers, is due to WordPress core issue. I can't fix that. It's not a theme issue ;)

Comment: in general it will be hard to silence that specific error without silencing all other similar, or having to change your code on every bbpress update

Comment: it is bullshit when someone produces code and calls it stable while it emits php warnings. The minimum that bbpress should do is to surpress the error. This is not "bbpress can not resolve it" this is "bbpress prefers someone else to put the effort to resolve it"

Comment: and from actually reading the tickets, there is no way core will change behaviour, so at best JJJ is delusional, at worse he is lazy

Comment: Oh with that I agree completely. It's shoddy work on their part imo, especially since it's been happening for over 3 years now...

Answer (score 2):

"Technically" it's just a PHP warning and not an error, and you should not have warnings enabled on production servers.  You can disable PHP from logging warnings and it will still log errors to the error log file.

You can disable PHP warnings by setting it in a custom php.ini file on the server (all errors except for warnings):
`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_WARNING`

or try setting it with PHP:

`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);`

From `php.ini` file:

```
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
; Development Value: E_ALL
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
; http://php.net/error-reporting
```

Comment: Sure, but I find - 'just disable error logging' approach a bit dishonest. Especially for a client. Anyways, it's probably a thing that bbPress developers should fix ultimately, don't know why they didn't...

Comment: It's not dishonest, it's disabling **warnings** not errors ... and this would be a perfect use case scenario.  I manage multiple racks in numerous data centers for clients ... you shouldn't have warnings enabled on a production servers anyways, those issues should be resolved before the site hits a production server.

Comment: I wasn't enabling them on production ;) But this was happening while developing, and was annoying :D

Comment: Yeah in that case then you're going to be SOL until bbpress issues an update. .. if they do

Answer (score 0):

```
/ Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

Check this